# How to make laravel pagination pretty instead of query params in Laravel 10?

Tags: laravel, pagination, friendly-url, paginator, pretty-urls

I want to change pagination default from ?page=2 to /page/2

I have tried `https://github.com/spatie/laravel-paginateroute` but it is archived & used for old Laravel verisons.

How can I implement this?

Comment: Have you tried with $paginator->withPath('/page')?

Comment: @HiteshPadhara it will not solve the problem: it will return `page?page=2`

Comment: Could you share the paginate query and route here?